# PDFBox command line merge tool warnings

Tags: merge, pdfbox

I am seeing issues when running PDFBox command line tool merge capability.

Both pdfbox-app-2.0.26.jar and pdfbox-app-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar report the same potential issue.  I am trying to merge, for example, 132 PDF files created by Edge browser from emails in HTML format. Emails in HTML format are generated by the free MBox Viewer application.

PDFBox will log more than 65,000 of warnings as below:

```
May 19, 2022 12:07:23 PM org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility appendDocument
May 19, 2022 12:07:23 PM org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility mergeIDTree
WARNING: key node00000001 already exists in destination IDTree
May 19, 2022 12:07:23 PM org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility mergeIDTree
WARNING: key node00000002 already exists in destination IDTree
May 19, 2022 12:07:23 PM org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility mergeIDTree
WARNING: key node00000009 already exists in destination IDTree
```

The generated merge file seems to be ok but it is hard to know without comparing individual PDF files with the merged file.

I would like to understand potential issues when the above warnings are logged by the PDFBox. I have cloned v3 of PDFBox from github, installed maven and built the pdfbox-app-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar without any problems. The warnings are generated in the file

```
pdfbox\pdfbox\src\main\java\org\apache\pdfbox\multipdf\PDFMergerUtility.java by mergeIDTree() function 
(see at the bottom).
```

I am looking for help to understand implications of the warnings since the PDFBox is a very large and complex project. During the merging process, it appears that IDs created for each PDF document are merged into a single destination container. I am not sure, but it appears that IDs represent COS objects. Each object has an associated unique key in the form of node00000001 for example. I don't know how to import the project into a  visual debugger to browse and run the code. I am new to Java.

It appears that the same key may appear in different PDF documents. Not sure how keys are generated for each PDF document. Question is whether different objects end up having the same key ? Sounds like that might be the case otherwise why PDFBox would log warnings. If the collision of keys is an issue, why PDFBox would not assigned unique key ranges to each PDF document, such as node00000001-node00000100 to the first PDF document,  node00000101-node00000200 to the second document and so on. I suspect that this would result in a huge IDTree structure and likely increase the size of the generated PDF, but could potentially address the warnings. This Is just my guess since I have no understanding of the merging process and I probably should not speculate.

```
private void mergeIDTree(PDFCloneUtility cloner,
            PDStructureTreeRoot srcStructTree,
            PDStructureTreeRoot destStructTree) throws IOException
    {
        PDNameTreeNode<PDStructureElement> srcIDTree = srcStructTree.getIDTree();
......
        Map<String, PDStructureElement> srcNames = getIDTreeAsMap(srcIDTree);
        Map<String, PDStructureElement> destNames = getIDTreeAsMap(destIDTree);
        for (Map.Entry<String, PDStructureElement> entry : srcNames.entrySet())
        {
            if (destNames.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
            {
                LOG.warn("key " + entry.getKey() + " already exists in destination IDTree");
            }
            else
            {
                destNames.put(entry.getKey(),
                              new PDStructureElement((COSDictionary) cloner.cloneForNewDocument(entry.getValue().getCOSObject())));
            }
        }.......
```

Comment: This is related to the structure tree, which is for accessibility (e.g. screen readers). So your file is no longer properly accessible after the merge. Renaming it here isn't enough, one would have to rename these at lots of other places :-(

Comment: I agree that renaming keys while doing final merge into IDTree is not not a solution since PDFBox would have to go back and fix many things. I was thinking to avoid creation of duplicate keys while reading PDF documents. It appears that keys are created as "node" + "n" number. Assuming it is possible for PDF reader  to know the highest "n" already used, that would allow to avoid creation of duplicate keys.

Comment: I am looking for two things: 1) Is my merge file content corrupted when I see warnings, and 2) what is th epotential solution.

Comment: As I said, the structure tree of the result file will not work properly. Display is no problem. The solution would be to implement the missing part. Might take a few weeks if anybody is interested. Alternatively, delete the structure tree in both files.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation. As long as the display works fine, I believe that is most important to users of MBox Viewer.

Comment: Separate but related question. Is there a way to disable/enable log events using official pdfbox app jar file? I was browsing this site and other sites but didn't find clear answer. Upon startup, will pdfbox read logger configuration file with the default name or configured via environmental variable? Example would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: No this is done in the logging library you use. I use log42, see e.g. this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28220823/535646

Comment: I will examine the link and the logging code. I finally managed to import PDFBox project into Eclipse via the import Existing Maven project option. Not sure whether that is the recommended way to make local changes and debug the application. In general I prefer not to distribute modified PDFBox or any other application as the part of MBox Viewer package. It may not be even possible due to import/export restrictions and/or PDFBox project license restrictions.