# PDFBox merge command tool problem with Log4JLogger

Tags: java, maven, logging, pdfbox

This is to follow up my post
[PDFBox command line merge tool warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72311473/pdfbox-command-line-merge-tool-warnings?noredirect=1#comment127788729_72311473)

Here are my notes and questions from  investigation into PDFBox merge command line tool and loggers.

I will refer to the following jar files in my post:

**pdfbox-app-2.0.26.jar** - this is official jar file downloaded from PDFBox site

**pdfbox-app-3.0.0-alpha3.jar** - this is official jar file downloaded from PDFBox site

**pdfbox-app-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar** - jar file built locally from  github source by me

My initial goal was to have ability to control level of logging by PDFBox merge tool using the file configuration. Specifically the ability to suppress large volume of WARNINGS logged by PDFBox during merge process of large number of PDF email files in PDF format. During the investigation I faced a number of challenges due my lack of Java skills and was forced to learn more than I anticipated, skills gap is still huge -:(

**Default Logger Case**

First, I  enabled diagnostics during startup to discover which logger, Jdk14Logger or Log4JLogger, is being selected by default. I did run the following command file:

```
@echo off

set diag=-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.diagnostics.dest=STDOUT

del merge.pdf

echo "########## java %diag% -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.26.jar PDFMerger pdf1.pdf pdf2.pdf merge.pdf"
java %diag% -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.26.jar PDFMerger pdf1.pdf pdf2.pdf merge.pdf

del merge.pdf
echo "######### java %diag% -jar pdfbox-app-3.0.0-alpha3.jar merge -o merge.pdf -i pdf1.pdf -i pdf2.pdf"
java %diag% -jar pdfbox-app-3.0.0-alpha3.jar merge -o merge.pdf -i pdf1.pdf -i pdf2.pdf

del merge.pdf
echo "######## java %diag% -jar pdfbox-app-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar merge -o merge.pdf -i pdf1.pdf -i pdf2.pdf"
java %diag% -jar pdfbox-app-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar merge -o merge.pdf -i pdf1.pdf -i pdf2.pdf
```

The jar command reported the same set of loggers present, including Log4JLogger, in  all pdfbox-app* jar files.

```
$ jar -tf pdfbox-app-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar|grep -i logger
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/AvalonLogger.class
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/Jdk13LumberjackLogger.class
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/Jdk14Logger.class
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/Log4JLogger.class
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/LogKitLogger.class
```

However, pdfbox-app-2.0.26.jar, pdfbox-app-3.0.0-alpha3.jar and pdfbox-app-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar all failed to select the Log4JLogger and selected the Jdk14Logger instead.

```
[LogFactoryImpl@1524126153 from jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@205029188] No user-specified Log implementation; performing discovery using the standard supported logging implementations...
[LogFactoryImpl@1524126153 from jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@205029188] Attempting to instantiate 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger'
[LogFactoryImpl@1524126153 from jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@205029188] Trying to load 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' from classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@205029188
[LogFactoryImpl@1524126153 from jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@205029188] Class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' was found at 'jar:file:/C:/Users/tata/Documents/PDFBox/pdfbox-app-3.0.0-alpha3.jar!/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/Log4JLogger.class'
[LogFactoryImpl@1524126153 from jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@205029188] The log adapter 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' is missing dependencies when loaded via classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@205029188: org/apache/log4j/Priority
[LogFactoryImpl@1524126153 from jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@205029188] Attempting to instantiate 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger'
```

I am  able to control the level of logging when running any of PDFBox app jar file using the below commons-logging.properties basic configuration file

```
@echo off

set diag=-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.diagnostics.dest=STDOUT
set properties=-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\tata\Documents\PDFBox\commons-logging.properties
set logger=-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger
set xml=-Dlog4j.configurationFile=C:\Users\tata\Documents\PDFBox\log4j2.xml

del merge.pdf
set vmargs=%diag% %properties%
echo "########## java %vmargs% -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.26.jar PDFMerger pdf1.pdf pdf2.pdf merge.pdf"
java %vmargs% -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.26.jar PDFMerger pdf1.pdf pdf2.pdf merge.pdf

del merge.pdf
set vmargs=%diag% %properties%
echo "######### java %vmargs% -jar pdfbox-app-3.0.0-alpha3.jar merge -o merge.pdf -i pdf1.pdf -i pdf2.pdf"
java %vmargs% -jar pdfbox-app-3.0.0-alpha3.jar merge -o merge.pdf -i pdf1.pdf -i pdf2.pdf

del merge.pdf
set vmargs=%diag% %properties%
echo "######### java %vmargs% -jar pdfbox-app-3.0.0-alpha3.jar merge -o merge.pdf -i pdf1.pdf -i pdf2.pdf"
java %vmargs% -jar pdfbox-app-3.0.0-alpha3.jar merge -o merge.pdf -i pdf1.pdf -i pdf2.pdf
```

The content of commons-logging.properties configuration file:

```
#
# https://cyntech.wordpress.com/2009/01/09/how-to-use-commons-logging/

# commons-logging.properties

#The commons logging log levels correspond to the java.util.logging.Level levels like this:

#fatal = Level.SEVERE
#error = Level.SEVERE
#warn = Level.WARNING
#info = Level.INFO
#debug = Level.FINE
#trace = Level.FINEST

# So, if you want to set your class to log all debugs, you use LEVEL.FINE.  
# These are also in order of priority, so, like in our example, 
# if you set your class logger to FINE, then trace log messages will not be recorded.

# jdk handlers
# disable all logging
#handlers=
# enable file logging
#handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler
# enable file and console logging
#handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

# default log level
.level=INFO

# Specific logger level
#PDFMergerUtility.level=SEVERE

# FileHandler level can be set to override the global level:
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=SEVERE
# ConsoleHandler level can be set to override the global level:
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=INFO

# log file name for the File Handler
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=javalog%u.log

# Specify the style of output (simple or xml)
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

# Optional - Limit the size of the file (in bytes)
#java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=50000

# Optional - The number of files to cycle through, by
# appending an integer to the base file name:
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=1
```

**Explicit Request for Log4JLogger**

I did try to explicitly request Log4JLogger but it didn't work, PDFBox jar generated exceptions.

```
java -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.diagnostics.dest=STDOUT -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger -Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:C:\Users\tata\Documents\PDFBox\log4j2.xml -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.26.jar PDFMerger pdf1.pdf pdf2.pdf merge.pdf

[LogFactoryImpl@1480010240 from jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@205029188] Attempting to load user-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger'...
[LogFactoryImpl@1480010240 from jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@205029188] Attempting to instantiate 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger'
[LogFactoryImpl@1480010240 from jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@205029188] Trying to load 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' from classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@205029188
[LogFactoryImpl@1480010240 from jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@205029188] Class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' was found at 'jar:file:/C:/Users/tata/Documents/PDFBox/pdfbox-app-2.0.26.jar!/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/Log4JLogger.class'
[LogFactoryImpl@1480010240 from jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@205029188] The log adapter 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' is missing dependencies when loaded via classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@205029188: org/apache/log4j/Priority
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.pdfbox.tools.PDFMerger.merge(PDFMerger.java:61)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.tools.PDFMerger.main(PDFMerger.java:49)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.tools.PDFBox.main(PDFBox.java:81)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: User-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' cannot be found or is not useable.
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:804)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:541)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:292)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.<clinit>(PDFMergerUtility.java:90)
    ... 3 more
```

**Adding v1.2.17 of log4j to PDFBox project**

I noticed that that there no jar file in C:\Users\tata.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.12 directory. Therefore , I  attempted to install the latest v1.2.17. Added the below to F:\PDFBox2\pdfbox\tools\pom.xml and rebuilt PDFBox. Maven installed jar files C:\Users\tata.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17 but that didn't resolve the issue with Log4JLogger. Not sure I updated PDFBox project correctly.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

At this point, I am not sure why I am having problem with Log4JLogger, what I am doing wrong and how I can resolve the issue.

Comment: I re-cloned PDFBox project to remove log4j dependencies  I added. I extracted all files from C:\Users\tata\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar jar running **jar xf** and determined that the jar file  already includes v1.2.17 of log4j2. Does anybody has working example of running official pdfbox-ap-xxx.jar file with Log4JLogger enabled and controlled via user provided log4j2.xml file and VM arguments (-Dxx) ?

Comment: Here's a config file for log4j2: https://pastebin.com/xxrr3VSH (put it into the resource directory)  here's the files needed for log4j2: https://pastebin.com/jkKX96es  I never used "Log4JLogger".

Comment: property for command line: `-Dlog4j2.configurationFile=`

Comment: I assumed incorrectly that v1.2.17 is the latest version of log4j. Sounds I will need to rebuild PDFBox jar in order to take advantage of log4j2.  I will play with log4j2 to learn but I will not be able to package and distribute my private version to users. Current PDFBox calls LogFactory.getLog() to create logger. LogFactory will iterate through a list of pre-configured logger names such as Log4JLogger, Jdk14Logger, and few other loggers trying to instantiate one. Can you advice which pom.xml and possibly other files I would need to update. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have plans to upgrade the official PDFBox build to log4j2?

Comment: log4j is not part of pdfbox-app. We use commons logging which accepts other loggers. The advice you asked for was given in the two links I posted.

Comment: Updated F:\PDFBox2\pdfbox\pdfbox\pom.xml and it seems to work. Will try to summarize later as Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to clarify questions I posted with the help from https://stackoverflow.com/users/535646/tilman-hausherr. Official PDFBox supports log4j but version 1 which is no longer supported. Official PDFBox fails to instantiate Log4jLogger and instantiate standard java logger Jdk14Logger instead. For typical usage, Jdk14Logger works just fine and it seems to be easy to configure. PDFBox Users need to be aware of that  and create and customize commons-logging.properties file to control logging. See example I provided in my Questions post.

The proper solution for developers and power users is to upgrade PDFBox to log4j version 2. I updated pdfbox/pdfbox/pom.xml as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/535646/tilman-hausherr and rebuilt PDFBox. Now I am able to configure logging by providing custom log4j2.xml file as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="FileAllLogs" fileName="logs/MyProj_all.txt" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
     <!-- log level precedence   ALL -> TRACE -> DEBUG -> INFO -> WARN -> ERROR -> FATAL -> OFF -->
     <!-- if you set level to WARN , all messages with the level on the right site will be logged -->
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
        <!-- set different level for file logger -->
        <Logger name="org.apache.pdfbox" level="warn" additivity="false">
         <AppenderRef ref="FileAllLogs"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Basic configuration of log4j2 seems to be a bit more tricky than for Jdk14Logger.